# 2007 Jeep Wrangler HOT OIL! STRANDED! HELP!

Tags: oil, jeep, wrangler

2007 Jeep Wrangler. Hot oil light came on, pulled over at a store, killed it, added some oil after it cooled about 15 minutes now it doesn’t want to start again thought about adding some coolant but afraid I might crack something. Please help I hope I haven’t already done damaged

Comment: When you say "doesn't want to start", does that mean "will turn over when I turn the key but won't keep running" or "nothing happens when I turn the key"?

Comment: Also what is the "hot oil" light? Is that really an oil temperature indicator? Or was it indicating "low oil"?

Comment: The hot oil posted underneath my prnd. The Elictrical was fine. Added some violent, it started up. But started driving again and it’s making a ringing sound and the “hot oil” keeps flashing

Comment: Sounds like oil starvation caused a spun bearing. Now it won’t hold oil pressure.  3K?

Answer (score 3):

Does your "hot oil light" look like this:

[image]

Because that is the low oil pressure light. And it means your engine doesn't have enough oil to run. The engine will destroy itself if run without enough oil. You should stop driving immediately and have the vehicle towed to be repaired.

The low oil level light tends to look similar:

[image]

But is less serious.

If it's flashing that's manufacturer and model specific, so you'll have to give more information.

Comment: Actually, it's the "low oil pressure light". The "low oil light" is different. You can perfectly well run an engine with slightly low oil level, as long as it is enough to have proper oil pressure. The correct action for low oil level is to add oil whenever convenient; the correct action for low oil pressure is to turn off the engine immediately, stop driving and have it towed.

Comment: Yep, corrected.

Comment: @juhist while some engines will run just fine with low oil I wanted to add warning that low oil level can be very harmful for other engines even without oil pressure alert. Also some won't allow starting when oil level is either too low or too high. Might be that all Jeep engines can tolerate these, I dont know, but I've added this as general warning if someone thinks this would always apply to all engines and models.